# How does Ruby detect a carriage return in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, carriage-return

I'm iterating through a large string that has several carriage returns. I'd like my logic to do something every time a carriage return is discovered (create a new ActiveRecord instance with all the string content before the carriage return).

Comment: could you please show what you have done so far?

Comment: Are you looking for [`String#each_line`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-each_line)?

Comment: I did not know about that one either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def doit(str)
  start_idx = 0
  while i = str.index("\n", start_idx)
    action str[0..i-1]
    start_idx = i+1
  end
end

def action(str)
  puts "This is what I've read: #{str}"
end
```

```
doit("Three blind mice,\nsee how they run.\nThey all ran after the farmer's wife\n")
  # This is what I've read: Three blind mice,
  # This is what I've read: Three blind mice,
  # see how they run.
  # This is what I've read: Three blind mice,
  # see how they run.
  # They all ran after the farmer's wife
```

See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-index).

If you only want to pass the portion of the string since the previous newline, change the line:

```
action str[0..i-1]
```

to:

```
action str[start_idx..i-1]
```

Comment: I don't know Rails so have just passed the string to the method `action`. I assume creating the `ActiveRecord` instance is straightforward.